# how to make a video from timeline position data?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-capture, video-processing

So I have timeline position data available to me as a JSON object where a object is being moved around a screen.  I want to be able to make a video using that information.  How would you suggest going about doing that?  (Ubuntu or OSX environment).

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a project letting users to edit videos on their phones and generate mp4 for them on the cloud.

My solution for the server side is using OpenGL to render the scene using the raw resources which could be video clip or an image and a timeline configuration xml file.

For each frame I grab the rendered pixels and input to ffmpeg which eventually encodes the frames into video.

I use OpenGL because it is highly portable and utilizes the power of GPU and gives rapid rendering speed even for 1080p videos. You may replace it with software render libraries such as OpenCV to render your frames, but you'll see great performance differences if you spin and add filters to your images.

The use of ffmpeg is quite popular and you will be able to find lots of documents and tutorials. You'd be able to find ffmpeg wrappers for java and Qt C++ if you like to work in a more relaxing program language environment.